# cordova phonecalltrap plugin and google play device compatibility

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, google-play, telephony

I've built a Cordova/phonegap application that is using speech synthesis.
In order to avoid disturbing phone calls on smartphones, I'm using the phonecalltrap plugin (io.gvox.plugin.phonecalltrap) to detect any incoming or ongoing phonecall, to prevent speech synthesis in that case.

The issue is that, though it perfectly works (useless actually) when installing manually on tablets that can't receive phone calls, using the phonecalltrap plugin makes the application incompatible with tablets on Google Play.

The reason is that it has the following prerequisites added to the APK:

```
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.telephony'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.telephony' reason='requested a telephony permission'
```

Now, I could remove the prerequisites by modifying AndroidManifest.xml before compilation and build an APK that doesn't have the above prerequisites.

BUT in that case, the phonecalltrap plugin is not supported anymore... (doesn't work)

What is the common practise in this case?

I don't think that building TWO different applications, one for tablets, one for smartphones, to have both support on Google Play is a good way to go since it would split user bases in two, just for a stupid little "feature".
I think there should be a way to tell Google play "use hardware telephony if available", not "this app needs telephony hardware".

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution, reading:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements

So what I did to ensure that this option was passed properly at Cordova build time and that there was no requirement on phone hardware, was to modify $PROJETC/plugins/android.json adding the android:required=\"false\" option to the plugin permission this way:

```
                    {
                        "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE\" android:required=\"false\" />",
                        "count": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS\" android:required=\"false\" />",
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "xml": "<uses-feature android:name=\"android.hardware.telephony\" android:required=\"false\" />",
                        "count": 1
                    }
```

This way, platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml is generated with the correct permissions at build time and the application becomes tablet-compatible on Google Play.

I'm leaving my question and answer, hopefully it can be useful to someone!